# Invalid key code when trying to fire a CTRL key pressed

Tags: java, keyevent

I'm trying to fire a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> pressed key, but I get an `Invalid key code` in the `keyPress` method. I can't find out why, Can't we use the keyPressed method to fire a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> pressed key?

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;



public class MainTest extends JFrame{


    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {

        Robot r= new Robot();
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        MainTest mainF =new  MainTest();
        mainF.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_O) && ((e.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK) != 0)) {
                    System.out.println("woot!");
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Try with `KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL ` for the first `keyPress` .

Comment: Thnaks Berger that's work well for me, you can put it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL` instead of `KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK` for the first `keyPress`, this will actually hit the <kbd>Control</kbd> key .

```
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the [**InputEvent**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html) [**isControlDown()** method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#isControlDown()).

> **isControlDown**
>
> `public boolean isControlDown()`
>
> Returns whether or not the Control modifier is down on this event.

Your code will look like this:

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if ((e.isControlDown()) {
                System.out.println("woot!");
     }
}
```

You can check [this **tutorial**](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.awt.event/InputEvent/Java_InputEvent_isControlDown_.htm) for further details.